# how to ask for location then display with google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I want to write a program that will ask the users location using modernizer and display it using google maps. The most I could get up to was using geolocation to find your location coordinates, and trying to use the google maps api to get a map on my page.
jsfiddle.net/DavDaBomb21/279fbf8b/

Can you please tell me how I use both together in order to display a map on a webpage? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple way would be:

```js
function geoSuccess(position) {
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    $('.map-container').html(
        '<iframe width="300" height="170" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + lat + ',' + long + '&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>'
    );
};
function geoFail() {
    /* Not supported */
};
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoFail);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map-container"></div>
```

It won't work here, either on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/279fbf8b/3/), but you can try in IE if you enable geolocation or on secure HTTPS website - it works just fine.

Comment: how would i add my own styling on the map?